# How do I design a database with many columns combined into one?

Tags: mysql, database-design, implode

I have a tube website and one of the options is selecting categories the videos can go into. Uploaders can decide to select all 94 categories. My current design has 94 columns (plus others), one for each category. Is there a way I can combine all 94 of these into one column `categories` instead of `this cat 1`, `this cat 2`, etc. and then maybe implode the insert?

I was reading another Stack Overflow question and the advice there was to have new rows for each but I think it would be rather redundant to have 94 rows for one video upload?

Comment: What you have discovered is the need for database normalization. A column for each category is indeed a bad idea and needs to be fixed.  The concept of normalization is much too large for a comment; you’ll want to google it to learn what you need to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the suggestion of that other Stack Overflow question (which you did not cite).  Consider maintaining just three columns for your table:

```
CREATE TABLE video_categories (
    video_id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    category_id INT NOT NULL
)
```

That is, each record stores one user vote, per video, per category.  This is a fairly normalized design, and frees you from trying to maintain 94 different columns.  One obvious flaw in your current design is that should new categories be added, you would be forced to change your underlying table design.  Ideally, new incoming data should not break your table design.

The suggestion I made above makes it fairly easy to query the data.  For example, to find the number of videos which received a rating from a user containing three or more categories, we could try:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT video_id)
FROM
(
    SELECT video_id
    FROM video_categories
    GROUP BY video_id, user_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) t;
```

While the above query might look complex, doing the same thing with the categories strewn across 94 columns would be far more complex (and difficult to maintain).

Comment: Ok thank you. BTW, lol, I realized my mistake 3 days into writing the code when I have 94 if statements to retrieve data. I thought to myself, what the ... am I doing?

Comment: @DonaldFaulknor If it feels wrong, it usually is :-)

Comment: I understand that query fully, it's not complex. My queries are indeed complex. You simplified it very well for me, thank you.

Comment: Since I am going to be handling this a different way, maybe I can get some extra guidance. I'll do the search myself, I just need to know what to search for. You know how when you're posting a question on Stack Overflow and you insert tags? How can I get a category to be inserted everytime you type `category name,` <-- the comma inserts the category. Is that JQuery I would be using?

Comment: @Donald For JQuery issues you should really open a new question :-)

Comment: Just thought I would share (Joke's on me): After implementing some changes, I reduced code on one page from 1800 lines to 50 lines LMAO

Comment: So the lesson learned here is that database are designed to grow _rowwise_ when adding data, not column-wise.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep all of your one-to-one relationships in a single (normal) table.  (uploader's id, video's id, upload timestamp, status, etc.)

Then you can have a `video_categories` table for one-to-many relationships:

`video_id`
`cat_id`

This way you can have

```
1   |  4
1   |  45
1   |  91
2   |  3
3   |  17
1   |  9
```

Then you relate the first table to the second table based on the video's id or use pivot queries when needed.

This will lead to "more rows" in the one-to-many table, but obviously fewer columns and the best part is there will be no empty space or redundant data stored in either table.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear whether multiple users can upload the same movie, but in any case, a `user_id` of some kind should probably be part of your suggested schema.

Comment: I assume that would be the "main" video table as that would be one to one.  Merging that here would mean redundant data storage in my above table.  If there are duplicate uploaded movies, ensure that a single video_id is made which can access the one to many table.

Comment: Well, the videos are essentially homemade, so, unless multiple members of the family upload, they'll all be different.

Comment: Then putting the user_id in the one_to_many table will make redundant data storage.